# RX sample with restarting on 'first after pause'

Tags: rx-java

Could anybody suggest how to implement this case with rx java?
[image]

It looks like `sample`, but there are two differences:

1. The sample start with first emission (**1**), even if subscribed before.
2. If interval between two emittions (**4** and **5** in this example) exceeds sample rate (1 sec), the sample will restart on the latter emittion (**5**).

Comment: I think you can use a custom operator for specific requirement.

Comment: can you elaborate on 1) ? do you want to cache the first emission for any future subscriber?

Comment: Nope, no caching needed. Like a PublishSubject, not Behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This requires a custom operator (reliable) or composing with existing ones (less reliable):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] delay = { 0, 100, 250, 300, 900, 975, 1050, 1200 };

    Flowable.range(0, delay.length)
    .flatMap(v -> Flowable.timer(delay[v], TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .map(u -> (v + 1) + " @ " + delay[v] + " ms"))
    .compose(firstAndSample(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
    .blockingSubscribe(System.out::println)
    ;
}

public static <T> FlowableTransformer<T, T> firstAndSample(long delay, TimeUnit unit) {
    return f -> {
        Scheduler s = new SingleScheduler();
        return f.publish(g -> {
           return g.take(1)
           .concatWith(
               g
               .sample(delay, unit, s, true)
               .timeout(delay + 1, unit, s)
           )
           .retry(e -> e instanceof TimeoutException)
           ;
        });
    };
}
```

It works by phase-switching within a shared flow of the upstream (`publish`). In the 1st phase, it takes 1 item from upstream and then switches to the 2nd phase (`concatWith`). The 2nd phase samples the upstream (`sample`) and if the sampling doesn't emit anything after its period (`timeout`), it fails the substream and we switch to phase 1 again by retrying on the `TimeoutException` triggered. To ensure the sampling and timeout evaluation happens in order, a specific single-threaded `Scheduler` is used for both. (The less reliability comes from the phase change not being atomic as its components are distributed between multiple operators).

Comment: Nice approach, thank you. I use RX java 1, so will try to adop this example and try it.